# Move Folder with images

Tags: xcode

I am using Xcode and currently my images are on desktop , what is the right way to move them in to the folder?
(when I just copy paste them my project not builds).
is there any easy way to do that without re linking the images 1 by 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.In the Xcode project navigator, select the destination project or group for the item you want to add.

2.Choose File -> Add Files to “”.

3.Select the file or folder to add.

4.Select destination, folder, and target options, and click Add.

or

Just drag and drop your desktop folder into  Xcode project.

In your case the images are on desktop. So you have to check **Copy items into destination group’s folder** option. Select this option to create a copy of the selected file or folder in the workspace. Do this if you want to delete, move, or rename files or folders in the workspace without altering the original versions on disk.

[image]

For more details : Developer.Apple : [Adding an Existing File or Folder.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/Adding_an_Existing_File_or_Folder.html)

Comment: @Roma-MT: u r most welcome. btwn, u have no idea what doing :) from ur profile pic..lol

Comment: exactly :) I just moved to Xcode for iOS development so that how i feel also :)