# How to make Xcode to point for missed images

Tags: xcode

After [Move Folder with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21353734/move-folder-with-images) this question.

I followed the steps and everything is ok besides couple of things.

It seems like I missed couple of pictures while copying them to IDE,
however in simulator everything works fine , but on real device I missing some pictures.

I have more than 100 pictures , it would be a work for 2 days to go 1by1 and check if it's copied correctly , is there anyway to make Xcode to point what images he misses ? because it doesn't say anything no warnings no errors nothing , just on device there is no pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the objective-c runtime to swizzle out `imageNamed:` with your own implementation that checks if the image was loaded successful.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIImage (Debugging)

#if DEBUG

+ (void)load {
    //Exchange imageNamed: implementation
    method_exchangeImplementations(class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(imageNamed:)),
                                   class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(imageNamedDebug:)));
}

+ (UIImage *)imageNamedDebug:(NSString *)name {
    UIImage *image = [self imageNamedDebug:name]; // swizzled! actually calls original `imageNamed:` method
    if (!image) {
        NSLog(@"Can't load image with name \"%@\"", name);
    }
    return image;
}

#endif

@end
```

---

Also: If it works on simulator and not in the device you might have a case issue with your fileNames. The simulator usually runs on a file system that is case insensitive (i.e. File.jpg is the same as file.JPG), the device runs a case sensitive file system where those two files are different. So check your filenames.

Comment: Can I do it without the predefined debug ?

Comment: Xcode should define `DEBUG` for you. I encapsulated the code in `#if` to make sure that this code won't be in your app store version. You generally want to avoid shipping apps which use method swizzling. You can of course remove it, but I honestly would not ship this code. It's usefulness ends when you are done with debugging.