# Xcode rearange Files in Finder

Tags: xcode

I tried to rearrange my source code files in finder and now xcode shows them as deleted. Is there a way to tell xcode the new location of the file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21353734/move-folder-with-images

Comment: I already have the file in xcode, is there a way to do this without readding it and loosing all my outlets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the Missing file  (turns Red) and go to file inspector. Click on the folder button in file inspector and provide the correct path of the file.

For missing files like this in red.

[image]

set correct path as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the file in the left (navigator) panel. In Xcode open the right (Utilities) panel if it's not already open. Now click the "File Inspector" tab. You should see a part that says "Location" with a button that looks like a folder. Click that button and then navigate to the folder where you moved the files to. Bam! Xcode should now see it's there!